# Customise ReSharper generated Properties code

Tags: resharper

With reSharper -> Edit -> Generate Code -> Properties from this:

```
private int _age;
```

I get this

```
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }
```

which is alright, but what can I do if I want something like this:

```
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set 
            { 
                if (_age != value)
                {
                    _age = value; 
                    OnPropertyChanged("Age");
                }
            }
    }
```

Is there a way to customise ReSharper's output? FYI I'm on Visual Studio 2008, ReSharper v5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own ReSharper **Live Template** like so:

[image]

Then you can enter new properties with backing field and *OnPropertyChangedEvent* call by one step by typing in first letters of live template shortcut: `propWithChangeEvents`.
Then an intellisence list appears. You select ***propWithChangeEvents***, type the **field type** (i.e. *int*) and ***ENTER***, then **field name** (i.e. *age*) and ***ENTER***.
Then all is generated as you need.

That's for new fields/properties. If you really need the same for existing fields let me know it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [live template](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html) to do what you want.  I have a couple templates I use for custom property implementations.  It's pretty powerful stuff.